# Testing react-router v4 with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-router-v4

I have a simple app they use react-router v4

```
const App = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={() => <div>Home</div>}/>
    <Route path="/profile" component={() => <div>Profile</div>}/>
    <Route path="/help" component={() => <div>Help</div>}/>
  </Switch>
);
```

and test

```
jest.dontMock('../App');

import React from 'react';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import App from '../App';

describe('<App />', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <App/>
    </MemoryRouter>
  );

  console.log(wrapper.html());

  it('renders a static text', () => {
    expect(
      wrapper.contains(<div>Home</div>)
    ).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Why does this test fail?
[image]

My config:

- enzyme: 2.8.2
- react-scripts: 1.0.7
- react-test-renderer: 15.5.4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to provide `initialEntries` as well as `initialIndex`. 
In your case it should look like this:

```
const wrapper = shallow(
  <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']} initialIndex={0}>
    <App/>
  </MemoryRouter>
);
```

Other possibility is that you need `enzyme`'s `mount` instead of `shallow`.

`react-router` has some great documentation here:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/MemoryRouter

Comment: How to change this test if i would replace `contains` to `equals`?

Comment: There is https://github.com/blainekasten/enzyme-matchers library which allows you to write something like: `expect(wrapper.find(Component)).toBePresent()`. But you may not need additional library. Take a look at official `enzyme` documentation which has great explanation of available selectors. 

In your case something like `expect(wrapper.find(<div>Home</div>)).toHaveLength(1)` could work.

Comment: I was doing this but the problem is that them the child is memoryRouter (when on Mount) and you can't setState and so on

Comment: how to cover the lazy loading import statements ?